# If WHERE condition returns no result, try another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't want this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE condition1
OR condition2
OR condition3
```

Instead I want this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE condition1
    (if no result)
        try condition2
            (if no result)
                try condition3
```

How can I write this in MySQL? So if a result is found then don't try the conditions below it.

Comment: Why you want do this like that?

Comment: We need to know *why* you want to do that.  It sounds like you are trying to optimize the query for speed.

Comment: Does "if no result" apply per row or to the entire set with the given condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition1)

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition3 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition1) AND
                     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition2)
```

If first `SELECT` retuns any rows, then second and third will return no rows. Otherwise, if second `SELECT` retuns any rows, then third `SELECT` will return no rows. Otherwise take results from third `SELECT`.

Comment: Very clever, but still smells. :-)

Comment: @Kaii I agree, but it is always intriguing trying to solve little puzzles like this! :=)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to know which of the conditions was met you could use a UNION query like so:

```
SELECT *, 1 as `condition` FROM table WHERE <condition1>
UNION
SELECT *, 2 as `condition` FROM table where <condition2>
UNION
...more conditions
```

Comment: Problem with this is that adding the `condition` column makes the resultset of each query different from the others, so this would show the result of all the querys.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1664/10)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `value` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (3, 'c'),
    (4, 'd'),
    (5, 'f'),
    (6, 'h'),
    (7, 'i')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE value = 
(case when exists (select 1 from table1 where value='e') then 'e'
     when exists (select 1 from table1 where value='a') then 'a'
     else 'i' end)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1664/10/0)**:

```
| ID | VALUE |
|----|-------|
|  1 |     a |
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` performs very bad in InnoDB. This is a valid solution, but also the one with the most computational overhead!

Comment: I give -1 for a valid solution that is inferior to all other already posted solutions. Sorry. The problem is, IT LOOKS GOOD. but it performs bad - and novices may think this is a clever way. WHICH IT ISN'T. it's painful.

Comment: Ok,,so now we can't give other valid solution that are not already post...pathetic

Comment: You can give as many "valid" solutions as you want. As long as you let the community decide which is good, and which is bad. :-)  good luck and stop revenge voting. Thanks for your fairness.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using a WHERE EXISTS statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EXISTS
{Condition 1}
OR EXISTS
{Condition 2}
...more conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a union like so:

```
WHERE condition1 
OR (condition2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition1))
OR (condition3 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition1)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition2)
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE val = if(condition1, 'result1', if(condition2, 'result2', if(condition3, 'result3','result')))
```